Refused Post Request to an API
I try to send a post request to my API but there is an error says
Refused to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
This is the error from the API as I catch the error
message: "Network Error"
It is a simple post request by axios
    import axios from 'axios';
    export const login = async (email, password) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: {
        email,
        password
      }
    }); 
    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

I want put the endPoint of the API because it doesn't reach there.
here is all middleware I used, maybe it cause the problem:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //to use static files like css in public          folder
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(helmet());

app.use(express.json());

app.use(mongoSanitize());

app.use(xss());

app.use(
  hpp({
    whitelist: [
    'duration',
    'ratingquantity',
    'pricediscout',
    'maxGroupSize',
    'difficulty',
    'price',
    'ratingAverage',
   ],
  }),
);

I try to eliminate the middleware but it doesn't work.

I see you are using Helmet which is a prime suspect for this issue. You can configure it to disable content security policy or remove the meta tag CSP and add connect-src rules in the helmet options.
Possible fixes:

Disable Helmet content security policy, helmet.contentSecurityPolicy() and use meta tag to deliver CSP.
Remove meta tag CSP and add connect-src rules into helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)

For 2, try this:
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      connectSrc: ["'self'", 'http://127.0.0.1:3000']
    }
  }
}));

For more details, please see a similar question here
